# Does it make diffrence in speed efficiency of code if we assign property of object to another variable and then use it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wonder does it make difference if I use another variable to access the property of object once and for all or access the data that I want , from the object each time :

> data = {position: [{X:12},{Y:4}] ,name : 'Smth'}

is there any diffrent between the following method :

> ```
> const X = data.position[0].X
> for(...){
>  ...do somthing with X
>  }
> ```

or

> ```
> for(...){
>  ...do somthing with data.position[0].X
>  }
> ```

Comment: In my understanding, yes there will be some difference. Storing in a temp variable should run faster.

Comment: Also depends on if any of the properties are getters or not.

Comment: In terms of performance, I think the *difference would be in nano-seconds or no difference at all*. The **real reason** why you should initialize the variable first is - **"If the value is expected to change within the loop and developer hasn't anticipated that change, then there could be some unexpected results and issues."**

Comment: Technically, the first is probably slightly faster, but whether or not that makes any difference in a real world piece of code would be something you'd have to test by measuring your actual real code.  Chances are, it does not make a material difference unless this was extremely performance sensitive code and unless you were accessing it a lot of times.  The general rule I follow is that if I have to access a multiple depth property more than once, then I load it into a local variable first and I do it more for programming convenience than performance.

Comment: Go for convenience

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some different is exist. Every time when you call property `js interpreter` [try to find calling property](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design-Elements#fast-property-access) (or method) at prototype hierarchy.

> **Most** JavaScript engines use a dictionary-like data structure as storage for object properties - each property access requires a dynamic lookup to resolve the property's location in memory. This approach makes accessing properties in JavaScript typically much slower than accessing instance variables in programming languages like Java and Smalltalk.

If you use variable to cache some data it will be faster than you use direct access. 
[There is some great benchmark to test it.](https://jsperf.com/access-to-property)

Comment: Nice link, can you elaborate and support *js interpreter try to find calling property (or method) at prototype hierarchy* with some sources?

Comment: @gurvinder372, see update of the answer. But bear in mind exist a lot of browsers and some of them has `closed source code` and main cause of a lot of the information on page which I mentioned **is not accurate** anymore.